# Give a bounty, but making sure a current answer doesn't get it

Tags: support, bounty

Well, I asked a question a few days ago that got me literally stuck without any solution I can think of. I hence wish to put a bounty since the problem seems quite complex.

However, the question already has an answer; yet this answer is completely wrong and unhelpful (as in it points as a complete different idea that *cannot* be the problem in the first place).

Can I make sure this answer doesn't get the bounty if no answer comes in time?

Comment: Meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: start by downvoting that answer and it won't get the bounty because it was added before. Only new answers with +2 or more can get the auto-reward

Comment: Re *"literary stuck"*: Don't you mean *"[literally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/literally#Adverb) stuck"*? (I am not sure about the whole [literally vs. figuratively](https://writingexplained.org/literally-vs-figuratively-difference) thingy.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen in spite of the joke I think the process is quite literally stuck: the process isn't moving forward or backwards without any further hints in my question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif so why start with downvotes? The existing answer is never going to be auto awarded, regardless of score.

Comment: @paul23 If you're trapped in mud or glued to something then you're "literally stuck". If you can't solve a problem, that's just being "stuck".

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm guessing the suggestion to downvote is because OP says the answer is wrong and unhelpful. (I don't think they meant to say that the vote was necessary to prevent it getting the bounty, it's just confusingly worded.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters as BSMP said, it's not about the bounty. If the answer is *completely wrong and unhelpful* then it should be downvoted and let's hope it will get deleted

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing you need to do because automatic bounty awarding ***never goes to existing answers***.

Automatic bounty awards only are given to answers that were posted *after* the bounty started. See the [FAQ on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer **that was posted after the bounty was started**, that answer is awarded the full bounty.
>
> Otherwise, either all or half of the bounty will be awarded to the highest-scored answer among those which meet all of the following:
>
> - They were **posted *after* the bounty was started**, and
> - [...]

(Bold is emphasis mine)